# OneSignal background notification in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, onesignal

I am working with OneSignal notifications in my application and would like to implement Background notification as described here 
[Background Notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding) but I am unable to find any Xamarin specific example, is it possible in xamarin or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check this? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup

Comment: @G.hakim yes I have read this and I am able to recieve notifications but I am specifcally talking about the background notifications https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications#section-setup-and-send-background-notifications

Comment: Quite honestly there is nothing in that link that you have in your question that cannot be converted in c# for xamarin android